# jq set a property in a json to an integer value

Tags: json, integer, jq, numeric

I have a json which contains

```
"memoryConfiguration" : {
    "optimizeMemorySettingsOnSave" : true,
    "availableMemory" : "30167040",
    "sharedBuffers" : 209715,
    "workMem" : 4194,
    "effectiveCacheSize" : 786432,
    "maintenanceWorkMem" : 65536
  },
```

I need to change the availableMemory setting to an integer so it looks like this:

```
  "memoryConfiguration" : {
    "optimizeMemorySettingsOnSave" : true,
    "availableMemory" : 30167040,
    "sharedBuffers" : 209715,
    "workMem" : 4194,
    "effectiveCacheSize" : 786432,
    "maintenanceWorkMem" : 65536
  },
```

My script (in bash) sets it as a string (with the double quotes):

```
SETMEM=200000 jq --raw-output --arg MyMemSetting $SETMEM '.memoryConfiguration.availableMemory=$MyMemSetting'  my_json_file.json
```

I know that there is a `|tonumber` available but cannot seem to figure out the syntax to get it working when setting a property.

Any help?

Comment: Please take a look at [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

The question as posted raises several issues that are addressed in the following two possible solutions.

1. To achieve the desired effect using the `MEMSET=... jq ...` style, one could write:

```
MEMSET=200000 jq '
   .memoryConfiguration.availableMemory=(env.MEMSET|tonumber)
'  my_json_file.json
```

though this comes with a caveat (see below).  Notice that the value of the bash variable is a string.

2. To pass in an integer value as a JSON number, use --argjson rather than --arg:

```
MEMSET=200000
jq --argjson MyMemSetting "$SETMEM" '
  .memoryConfiguration.availableMemory=$MyMemSetting
' my_json_file.json
```

The caveat described below also applies in this case.

#### Caveat

All official releases of jq (through version 1.6) have a well-known "loss-of-precision" issue resulting from the use of IEEE 754 64-bit numbers to represent JSON numbers.  The representation issue was resolved by an update that was made on Oct 22 2019 (i.e. after the release of jq 1.6).

Comment: `--argjson` was the part that solved my issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So this a bash issue :

Look this example

```
 A=10    echo "="${A}"="
```

With this syntax A is defined in subshell of echo processes not the current

```
 B=20  ;  echo "="${B}"="
```

with ';' , you will have 2 different statements , so will define the variable , and the other will use